# Semi-linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that a function defined as $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i$ on a n-dimensional complex space is semi-linear functional. The additive property is straightforward but the conjugate homogeneous property is not so clear. It involves showing that $f(αx)  = βf(x)$ where β is the conjugate of α

Comment: I think it's $f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i \overline{x_i}$

Comment: See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilinear_map). It may be helpful